# Position div(s) up and down

Tags: html, css

[image]
I want to position a series of divs like this and I can't position each of them seperately. Is there any way to do it for all the divs at once. Plz Help ME

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do this by using class. Let's see

Use `dispaly: flex` in the parent class. Then use `align-self: start` or `align-self: end` in the child class. Read more about align-self [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/align-self)

```css
.container{
  display: flex;
  height: 120px;
}

.box{
  height: 70px;
  width: 40px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  margin: 0 3px;
}

.up{
  align-self: start;
}

.down{
  align-self: end;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box up"></div>
  <div class="box down"></div> 
  <div class="box up"></div> 
  <div class="box down"></div> 
  <div class="box up"></div> 
  <div class="box down"></div> 
  <div class="box up"></div> 
  <div class="box down"></div> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Use CSS `nth-child(odd)` to select the odd elements

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}

.child {
  border: 2px solid blue;
  margin: 5px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 80px;
}

.child:nth-child(odd) {
  margin-top: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's the way to go, yes, but according to the image the OP posted, it wouldn't be "odd", but "even" : `.child:nth-child(even)`, starting with the second one...

Answer (score 0):

```
// try this one this will work


  enter code here
container{
  display: flex;
  height: 120px;
}

.box{
  height: 70px;
  width: 40px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  margin: 0 3px;
}

.up{
  align-self: start;
}

.down{
  align-self: end;
}


<div class="container">
  <div class="box up"></div>
  <div class="box down"></div> 
  <div class="box up"></div> 
  <div class="box down"></div> 
  <div class="box up"></div> 
  <div class="box down"></div> 
  <div class="box up"></div> 
  <div class="box down"></div> 
</div>
```